# CPU Fan Error on Start of Desktop

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7

Over the last couple of days, my PC when starting up from cold displays CPU Fan Error - Please F1 to go to Setup.

Now, I will make it perfectly clear that my Desktop has not had a new Fan fitted since it was built in August 2014.

Anyhow, after you going to BIOS setup and then exit; the PC boots up as normal. You can close it down and restart it again as normal without any error message.

I have ensured that there is no dust in or around the Desktop just in case things might be getting too hot, plus in the BIOS screen, I changed the setting for CPU from Standard to Full Power.

The basic details of the machine are:

Intel Core i7.4790K CPU at 4GHz
Asus Z97P Motherboard with 32GB of RAM.

So, I have two questions:

1. Is this a problem with a faulty fan, and if so should I replace
   it
2. If it is not a problem - I do make the message go away? As I say
   it does not always come up

Answer (score 0):

I found that the heat sink after taking the fan off was covered in dust! So, carefully using a fine paint brush, I removed the dust and from around the fan and gently hoovered up the dust. I also applied a couple of drops of 3 in 1 machine oil to the fan's shaft.

After doing this, I restarted the machine. Error gone!!!

Answer (score -1):

Since your fan seems to be working it might be your motherboard, but you should be able to ignore these errors by entering into the BIOS and looking for the option "Halt on errors" and switching that to "None" or "Off". This will keep it from sitting at the BIOS screen waiting for you to press F1.

Comment: Hi, fan is fine. It starts up doesn't make any horrible noise and spinning around quite happily. Is there a way to determine if there is a problem with the motherboard?

Comment: There's no way to check if it's a problem with the motherboard without replacing the motherboard, and if the fan works properly that's likely the next option. I edited my original answer to add some information that might be helpful.

Comment: Just to add I booted the pc up and went to the Bios setting. I left the pc standing there and looked at the details. CPU Fan power went straight to 100%, and the CPU Temp was slowly creeping up, but on last look was 57 degrees. Is this still OK or too hot

Comment: That's way too hot to be sitting at the BIOS screen. Check that your heatsink isn't lose, those stock Intel heatsink clips have a nasty habit of breaking when they get old.